# Show this matrix has non-zero determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have a $T \times T$ symmetric matrix M. Every diagonal element of this matrix is $2^n$ and every other element of the matrix is a number from the set $\{2,4,8,\dots, 2^{n-1}\}$.

Is it possible to show this matrix will always have non-zero determinant?

Comment: @MF14, that matrix has determinant $1$ anyway

Comment: There is a sentence whose usefulness should be clarified : "no two rows are identical" : do you mean that, when sorted, the two sorted lists are different ?

Comment: I think this sentence is causing confusion. I'll remove it above

Comment: Another question. Has the $n$ in $2^n$ anything to to with the $T$, the size of the matrix?

Comment: No. They are unrelated.